# Powershell App Pool set periodicRestart syntax

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

I'm trying to set the [`periodicRestart`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart) property using a powershell script, but I'm trying to use a slightly different syntax than what I've seen in code samples.

Here's one way to do according to [Set the specific times to recycle an application pool with PowerShell](https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Set-the-Specific-Times-to-Recycle-an-Application-Pool-with-PowerShell#.VcEkn_lVhBc):

```
Clear-ItemProperty $iisAppPoolName -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
Set-ItemProperty   $iisAppPoolName -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule `
                                   -Value @{value="01:00:00"}
```

However, I already have a block of code where I'm setting properties on the `$appPool` itself like this:

```
$appPool = New-WebAppPool $iisAppPoolName 
$appPool.managedPipelineMode = "Classic"
$appPool.managedRuntimeVersion = "c4.0"
$appPool.recycling.periodicRestart.time = [TimeSpan]"00:00:00"
$appPool | Set-Item
```

Which works fine, so I'd like to add the following line:

```
$appPool.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule = @{value="01:00:00"}
```

But I can't get the syntax for `@{value="01:00:00"}` to take.  The `schedule` property is expecting a hashtable which is what I'm passing it.

[image: example]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's interesting that you're seeing it as a `[Hashtable]`. I see it as a `[Microsoft.Iis.Powershell.Framework.ConfigurationElement]`.

It has a method called `.UpdateCollection()` which expects a `[PSObject[]]`, so it's looking for an array of objects.

The thing is, calling that method, whether on a pool object returned from `New-WebAppPool` or from `Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\ExistingPool`, results in an error stating that it's read only.

I tried replacing the entire `.Collection` with a new arraylist with timespan objects added to it, and I got no errors, but it didn't set the values.

I also tried creating a ConfigurationElement object, but it seems to have no constructor, so it's probably a private class somewhere in the code.

I'm not saying there's *definitely no way* to do it like you want, but it seems like you'll be best off just using `Set-ItemProperty` as it seems that some of these attributes were designed to be updated only through the PS Provider.